# Delete/Drop columns with nulls values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to drop all columns from my table where all records are null.

My table looks as follows:

```
Locations [1]   [2]   [3]  [4]   [5]
[a]       10.00 Null  Null 20.00 Null
[b]       Null  30.00 Null Null  Null
```

Basically, I want to delete columns 3 and 5 from the above table. What would be the best way to do this?

Edit: Instead of manually going through the table to drop each column individually, is there a way where I can drop all columns with null records together?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't `DELETE` columns, you `DELETE` rows. Your requirement doesn't make sense.

Comment: Always use IS NULL to look for NULL values.

Comment: You need to clarify your question, as already stated, you can't `delete` a column, but you can `drop` a column, which means to remove it from the table definition. Is that what you want?

Comment: You can drop several columns in a single `alter` statement just separate them with a comma. If you want to programatically *find* and drop columns that contain nulls you'll need to write some Dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Larnu - this question makes perfect sense if you think outside the SQL limitation to row-wise operations only.  If there was an easy way to rotate the table (swap columns with rows) - it would not be a problem. I haven't heard of such a way, though.

Comment: The difference , @MichalJFigurski , is that `DELETE` is a specific operation in SQL Server. Since I made that comment, the OP has edited to clarify they mean `DROP` the column, but at the time what they were asking didn't make sense for the language that they are trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the values of a column for all *rows* (not records) are `null` you can use an aggregate such as

```
select max([1]), max([2])... from table
```

to remove a column you *drop* it

```
alter table <tablename> drop column <column name>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dynamic version of a script something like this

```
drop table if exists #Locations;
go
CREATE TABLE #Locations (
  [Location]        varchar(10) not null,
  [1]               decimal(12,2),
  [2]               decimal(12,2),
  [3]               decimal(12,2),
  [4]               decimal(12,2),
  [5]               decimal(12,2));
    
INSERT INTO #Locations([Location], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]) values
('[a]', 10.00, Null, Null, 20.00, Null),
('[b]', Null, 30.00, Null, Null, Null);

if not exists (select 1 from #Locations where [3] is not null)
    alter table #Locations
    drop column [3];

select * from #Locations;
```

```
Location    1       2       4       5
[a]         10.00   NULL    20.00   NULL
[b]         NULL    30.00   NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood ,to check the data that contain of values Null use this query like that:

```
  SELECT 1  --  with using a literal
      FROM (table)
    HAVING COUNT(a) = 0 
           AND COUNT(*) > 0;
```

After that remove the columns with using this query :

```
Alter table <Table Name> drop column <Column Name>
```